# How can I set specific response for 404 not found on Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have nginx configuration as below. I've added error_page configuration however it didn't work.
Nginx version is 1.14.1. The line of "error_page  404 /404.html" doesn't work , İs there any other solution? I want to response "IT WOKRS" when get 404. Error page parameter didn't work may be there is some other alternative solution.

Thanks.

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
 }

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format combined_ssl 'time_local="$time_local" server="$host" dest_ip="$server_addr" '
            'src="$remote_addr" '
            'protocol="$server_protocol" status="$status" '
            'bytes_out="$body_bytes_sent" bytes_in="$upstream_response_length" '
            'http_x_forwarded_for="$http_x_forwarded_for" '
            'uri_path="$uri" '
            'http_method="$request_method" response_time="$upstream_response_time" '
            'request_time="$request_time" ssl_protocol="$ssl_protocol" ssl_cipher="$ssl_cipher"';

    server_tokens off;   
    upstream app {
            server localhost:8080;
    }

    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ****.com.tr;
    server_name_in_redirect on;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    allow all;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!RC4:RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
    ssl_certificate /***.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /****.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "object-src data: 'unsafe-eval';";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    if ($request_method ~ ^(OPTIONS)$)
    {
        return 405;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        root   html;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://app;
        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
                            set $year $1;
                            set $month $2;
                            set $day $3;
                    }
                    access_log /****_8443-$year-$month-$day.log combined_ssl;
    }
    error_page  404  /usr/share/nginx/html/404.html;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Where is 404.html located? I test your config and 404 works fine.

Comment: if the config as below it work but the above's not working.
`worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
}}}`

Comment: everything is related to `root` and where is 404.html located.
you must put 404.html in root directory that you defined in config and it will work.

Comment: it doesn't related directory if it does The other config that I've edited previous command wouldn't have worked.

Comment: I've updated with 404.html location